# Files replication when rails app runs on multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cloud, high-availability, rackspace

My Rails3 application runs on multiple VPS servers on Rackspace. 
We allow users to upload images on our application and place those files at /public directory.

What is the best way to sync it across the servers.

Setup: Ubuntu 12.x OS/Nginx/Phusion

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replicating the data, why not side-load it to a standard location that is accessible by all of your VPSs?

That should reduce bandwidth overall, and storage costs, by only having one copy of the data.